AG Grid-- How to use default column filters for heirarchial grid
I am using hierarchical grid in angular. This consists of one level of expansion. When i apply filters for the first level, I am able to filter only the top level.
I wanted to filter the second level as well.
I am using the same fields for both child and parent.
I wanted to achieve this using the filters provided by ag-grid,but not using the custom filters
Here is the code sand box example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/hungry-burnell-27l8l5?
Any help for this issue would be appreciated!!
Thanks
Here is the code sand box example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/hungry-burnell-27l8l5?
